# Looking for a "game anime" with summoning monsters using stone circles

Tags: monster-rancher

I'm looking for an anime I saw when I was a kid. It was a game anime, rather typical, where a kid falls into a game and is trying to escape. I can remember that the characters fought using some kind of monster. They only had to summon it once, and did so by placing a stone circle into some kind of receiver. The main character's monster was called "Sweetcake", I think, and he was joined by a blonde girl and someone else. Pretty sure Sweetcake could talk, too. Does anyone know what this anime might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it could be **Monster Rancher** (also known in Japan as Monster Farm).

Here is a summary of the show from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_%28anime%29), bold emphasis is my own:

> The story follows a boy named Genki Sakura, who is a keen player of
>   the Monster Rancher video games. After winning a tournament hosted by
>   the game's creators, Genki wins a special CD that he can use to unlock
>   a special monster in his game at home. However, upon using this disk
>   in his game console, **he finds himself transported to a world of
>   monsters that, much like Genki's game, are given life by scanning
>   special stone disks within temples**. There, he meets a girl named
>   Holly, who is seeking a stone disk containing a legendary Phoenix that
>   will save the land from the tyranny of an evil ruler named Mu. Upon
>   attempting to use the disk Genki had won to try and release the
>   monster, they bring forth a different sort of monster, which Genki
>   names Mochi. Wanting to free the land from Mu's rule, Genki, Holly,
>   Mochi and their other monster companions go on a quest to find the
>   stone disk that contains the Phoenix.

One of the monsters mentioned in this summary, Mochi (sometimes also written as Mocchi), is the name of a Japanese confection. It seems that "Sweetcake" is used as a translation of this name sometimes, based on the results of Googling `monster rancher "sweetcake"`. Here is a picture of Mochi/Sweetcake which may help jog your memory more than written words.

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks man, I can finally stop thinking about it! And rewatch it, of course. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tom Interestingly enough, I've never seen the anime, but I've played a few of the games and your description seemed close enough. Glad I could help though :)